# Why does @XmlType propOrder affect json order?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, lombok

I am deploying a WS on Wildlfy Server 8.1.0.Final with the following dependencies:

```
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-validator-provider-11</artifactId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
```

Can you tell me why @XmlType changes the order in JSON response?

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@Builder
@XmlRootElement(name = "z")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor()
@XmlType(propOrder = {"a", "b", "c"})
public class Y{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "c")
    private BigDecimal c;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "b")
    private long b;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "a")
    private BigDecimal a;
}
```

I want to know why using @XmlType works for JSON . @JsonPropertyOrder doesn t work for me . :-s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameters order with and @XmlType(propOrder) and Resteasy jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099030/parameters-order-with-and-xmltypeproporder-and-resteasy-jackson)

Comment: I want to know why using XmlType works for JSON . JsonPropertyOrder doesn t work for me . :-s

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Jboss is trying to use `JsonPropertyOrder` from `org.codehaus.jackson` while I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`.

The solution is to put in POM scope provided

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```